# Improving the duty cycle of a linear actuator

Tags: dc-motor, components

My understanding is that a linear actuator (LA) must have an off period after running on load to allow the motor and gears to cool to prevent overheating damage.

I have a (12V 30W max) LA with a duty cycle of 10% and a max load of 750N.

2 minutes on / 18 minutes off

```
2 / 18 + 2 = 0.1
```

My questions:

- Does this mean that the LA will have to rest for 18 minutes after running at its maximum load of 750N for a duration of 2 minutes?
- Would it be possible to run the LA for more than 2 minutes at a lower load? For example, 10 minutes at 15N of load.
- What if you have the LA run for 2 minutes @ 15N with a lower off time?
- Do LAs have much of a use in locking systems, such as door bolts or similar?

Comment: "My understanding is a LA must have an off period after running on load to allow the motor and gears to cool to prevent overheating damage." This is incorrect, I have one here on my desk that is rated for continuous duty.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 2):

#1 : From what you stated yes.
#2 : With a much lower load it will be able to run longer. Make sure to monitor the temperature as heat is causing damage or premature wear.
#3 : With a much lower load the LA will take longer to heat.

If you measure the amps you can find your watt consumption P=V*I Doing this at different loads might help you determine what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Some things are designed for continuous duty, some for intermittent, depending on their cooling provisions, whether they're linear actuators, motors, shredders (my Dad seems to kill shredders for some reason!)

The need for intermittent operation is usually temperature rise limited. If you can measure the internal temperature, then you can operate at other duty cycles accurately. If not, then you're guessing. Operating at lower load ought to reduce the heat generated on some types of motor, but it's not universally guaranteed.

When in doubt, follow the instructions.